# After mouse click image disappears and shows up in new random position. How can I check the new position? (processing)

Tags: random, position, processing

I need help with my code in processing. It is actually a short and easy code, but I am a beginner in programming, so for me seems everything difficult... :(

My goal is...

- To click on an image.
- After the mouse click, the image should disappear and show up in a new random position.
- Then I should be able to click on the image in the new random position, and it should do the same again: disappear and show up in a new random position. and so on.

I have written some code (see below), but it does not work properly. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me to find out, what is wrong with my code. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Here is my code:

```
PImage pic; 

// Declare variables for the picture
float pic_x; 
float pic_y;
float pic_r = 100;

float pic_x_new = random(0, 400);
float pic_y_new = random(0, 400);

boolean mouseOverPic;

void setup(){
 size(500,500);
 background(0,100,0);

 //loading the picture
 pic = loadImage("pic.png");
 image(pic, pic_x, pic_y, pic_r, pic_r); 
}


void draw(){

 mouseOverPic = mouseX <= pic.width 
 && mouseX >= pic_x 
 && mouseY <= pic.height 
 && mouseY >= pic_y;

if (mousePressed && mouseOverPic) {
  background(100);
  image(pic, pic_x_new, pic_y_new, pic_r, pic_r);  
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to be more specific than saying your code does not work properly? Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to narrow your problem down? Which line of code behaves differently from what you expected?

The code you have doesn't make a ton of sense, because you're only ever drawing the image when it's being clicked. That doesn't sound like what you want to do. And your collision detection code is not correct. Try running through your code with some example values to see exactly what it's doing. I've written a tutorial on collision detection in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

To fix this, you really need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time. For example:

- Can you create a simple example program that just shows a hard-coded rectangle that changes color if the mouse is inside it?
- Can you then make it so the rectangle displays in a random location every time the program is run?
- Then can you make it so the rectangle changes location when you click it?

If you get stuck on a specific step, please narrow your problem down and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you test against `pic_x`, but uses `pic_x_new` to draw the image (same with `y`). You should use the same var to place and test the image.

Another approach would be to make a function to test mouse against the image passing the new values as parameters.